# Hide sequential Carriage Returns with CSS or JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I think this is impossible, but I'm asking anyway.  Given a `<pre>` tag with the following content, is there anyway in CSS and/or JS to strip the extra carriage returns so it's not basically quadruple-spaced?

```
Line 1



Line 2



Line 3
```

I tried using `br {display: none}` but they're not html line breaks.  As for JS, I tried the following based on another SO answer I found:

```
(function () {    
    var nodes = document.getElementsByClassName("longdesc");
    console.log(nodes.length)
    for (var n=0; n<nodes.length; n++) {
            nodes[n].textContent = nodes[n].textContent.replace(/[^\S\r\n]/, "test");
            console.log(nodes[n].textContent);
    }
})();
```

This seems to eradicate ALL carriage returns but only puts "TEST" in the first instance.

This is happening in a ticketing system when someone replies via email.  Every cr/lb in the email is doubled, it seems.

Comment: give a try to reduce line height if you do have a single line of text in between each groups of line break ( kind of : line-height:0.4em ), else clean it up on server side :)

Comment: Yeah unfortunately it's actually 3 carriage returns between each line of text.

Comment: you could remove these while treating it on server side

Comment: I wish, I'm just trying to hack this client side for my usability.  I don't own the system.

Comment: can we see the actual code that would be subject to your changes?

Comment: too bad, first idea was http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rOLJyR but it could be some bad surprise. you will need javascript to clean this up on user side since server side is not avalaible

Comment: I found a chrome plugin called `Web Override` that allows CSS and Javascript, so I updated my question to reflect that JS would be acceptable.

Comment: Updated the question again, I'm getting closer with JS I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works!

```
(function () {    
    var nodes = document.getElementsByClassName("longdesc");
    for (var n=0; n<nodes.length; n++) {
        nodes[n].textContent = nodes[n].textContent.replace(/\n{2,}/g, "\r\n\r\n");
    }
})();
```

Much <3 to https://regex101.com and #regex on freenode

Answer (score 1):

Use the below CSS

```
pre {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the way they have it set up the `white-space` attribute is already set to `pre-line`.  If I set it to no-wrap on that div I literally get no line wraps.

Comment: Oops!! http://jsfiddle.net/vsk21uy8/ but I tested with simple html you pasted and its working fine for that.

Comment: Oh, just add more and more specificity to the css rule and I think we can override it.

Comment: I have updated the question, I think I'm getting closer with JS